# Is there a difference between GLubyte and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE?

Tags: objective-c, opengl, opengl-es

I'm rendering an interleaved vbo using the following code which works fine.

```
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(InterleavedVertexData), (GLvoid*)((char*)0));
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(InterleavedVertexData), (GLvoid*)((char*)0+3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(InterleavedVertexData), (GLvoid*)((char*)0+6*sizeof(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)));
```

When I change glColorPointer's pointer paramater to use **GLubyte** i don't see anything rendered on the screen?  I'm defining colour as GLubyte in my struct also.

```
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(InterleavedVertexData), (GLvoid*)((char*)0+6*sizeof(GLubyte)));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GLubyte` is a type. `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is an integer constant which is often used to indicate that you will pass a `GLubyte` in a pointer.

`sizeof(GLubyte)` is always 1 by definition. Taking `sizeof(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)` will typically return 4 or 8, because it's an integer constant, and has the size of whatever your system's integer size is.

Answer (score 2):

`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` is a symbolic const while `GLubyte` is a type. GLubyte is commonly implemented as a typedef of `unsigned char`; you can confirm this by looking at your `gl.h`.

You should use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` inside your OpenGL method to specify the type of data you are passing along and use `GLubyte` to compute the size of your data.

Comment: `GLubyte` is not defined as a typedef for `unsigned char`. It is a common implentation, but OpenGL added the new type for a reason, it has another, more specific, meaning than `unsigned char`. C/C++ are quite relaxed in type sizes and such, `OpenGL` is not.

Comment: Did u look at the gl.h i mentioned in XCode because GLubyte is exactly define this way: typedef unsigned char   GLubyte;?

Comment: gl.h of any implementation is just that, an implementation, it is actually the spec that defines what GLubyte is. For example, suppose that on a certain platform char is 2 bytes to enable UTF-16 by default, then this wouldn't be a correct typedef and this would be implemented different..

Comment: I see your point now - since the question was  tag with opengl-es and xcode would it be ok to assume that unsigned char is the actual implementation of GLubyte?